# Android: Create ImageViews as and when they are needed

Tags: java, android, performance, android-imageview, android-view

I have a task in my application and I'm just trying to think of the most efficient way of programming it.
The aim is that when my application receives some new data then it should show a new ImageView on the screen, so if it receives three sets of data then three ImageViews should be shown on the screen and so on. This will only ever be up to 32 ImageViews.
So my question is, should I create the 32 ImageViews in my XML code so that they're already there but only made visible when they are needed or should I create them programmatically in my Java code as an array and create completely new ImageViews when new data is received?

Just looking for the most efficient way to program this for the best performance and cleanest code

Comment: why not use listview with custom listitem?

Comment: If that's the best way to go then I'll do that

Comment: I have no experience with listview's so I'll have to have a look into it. Is it possible to have a horizontal scrolling listview with multiple imageviews inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try recyclerView/ListView/GridView. They take care of create & reusing ImageViews for you.

If you really want to manage ImageViews yourself, e.g. you want to scroll quickly without jank caused by creating & initializing ImageViews, you could create 32 ImageViews programmatically at first, and use them when needed, like ImageViews pool.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So the best thing to do would be to create a listview with 32 imageviews in there ready to go when I need them?

Comment: You don't need that much. RecyclerView/ListView/GridView recycle and reuse ImageView automatically, Not all ImageViews are visible on screen. So you don't have to create 32, may be 10 is enough (depending on your device the ImageView size).